# Grammar of this sentence

Tags: grammar, syntax

For full context see [this document](https://www.docdroid.net/rLFVKUN/japanese-text.pdf), Exercise 7.

According to my textbook, the brackets have to be filled with:

1 ただ

2 すると

3 つぎつぎに

4 せっかく

5 ぜったいに

The sentence in question is the one at the very bottom.

> せっかく三十分も早く行ったのに、約束の時間に遅れるし、友人には買いたくないなら、ぜったいにそんなことを言ってはいけないと注意されるし、大変な一日だった。

I'd interprete it as follows:

> "Because I didn't make it in time even though I went to great pains to
>   be 30 minutes early and because I was warned by my husband that I must
>   not say that I don't want to buy anything, it was a horrible day."

I feel a bit unsure about my interpretation because there are several clauses embedded into each other. Maybe you can confirm whether I did it right or not.

Comment: 買いたくない**なら** is "**if** you don't want to buy."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split it into four parts like this:

1. せっかく三十分も早く行ったのに、
    Although I went to all the trouble to go to the place 30 minutes earlier,
2. 約束の時間に遅れるし、
   I was late for the appointment,
3. 友人には「買いたくないなら、ぜったいにそんなことを言ってはいけない」と注意されるし、
   my friend warned me saying "If you don't want to buy anything, you must never say such a thing",
4. 大変な一日だった。
   (so) it was a terrible day.

Note:

- 友人 is "friend", not "husband".
- 買いたくない**なら** is "*if* you don't want to buy".
- そんなこと ("such a thing") refers to ちょっと贈り物を探しているんです.
- The two ～し are explained in [this article](http://maggiesensei.com/2014/07/10/how-to-use-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%97-shi/). Using "because" is not too far, but usually it can be translated naturally without explicitly saying "because".